# making a list of multiple data frames in python for using in iteration

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have 100 data frames with these names in python:

df_0

df_1

df_2

...

I want to create a list from these data frame in order to use it in a loop. I want my list in this format:

dfs=[df_0, df_1, df_2, ..., df_99]

I would be thankful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: where do you have your pandas data frames? in 100 different variables? in a json file? in a SQL table? I need more information

Comment: in panda data frame

Comment: you are not answering my question, you have 100 different variables, one per data frame? How did you create the 100 dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow. The more details you can give about *how* your data was created, the more likely you are to get constructive feedback. In particular, try hard to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

It sounds like you have 100 variables floating around in your session and you want to put these into a loop.

## Cheap Answer

You're going to have to write out a lengthy statement like `dfs=[df_0, df_1, df_2, ..., df_99]` as you suggested. A quick-ish way to do this would be to copy the output of `['df_' + str(i) for i in range(100)]`.

## Better Answer

Somehow you're creating these 100 variables. Perhaps you're reading 100 database tables or reading 100 CSV files.. I'm not sure.. but this is where you should be building your list. For example, instead of doing something like

```
df_0 = pd.read_csv('path/to/file_0.csv')
df_1 = pd.read_csv('path/to/file_1.csv')
...
```

you should do something like

```
files = ['path/to/file_0.csv', 'path/to/file_1.csv', ...]
dfs = [pd.read_csv(x) for x in files]
```